# Max 3 values of every group

Tags: sql, group-by

I sorted my data to something like this and now I want to get top 3 max person_occurence by every company but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

```
   person_occurence company    person_id
    67               company_1  110
    66               company_2  176
    64               company_3  100
    64               company_3  196
    63               company_4  127
    62               company_1  150
    61               company_5  120
    60               company_3  140
    59               company_5  154
    59               company_5  162
    59               company_4  194
    58               company_4  109
    58               company_3  128
    58               company_1  156
```

I used this query to get max of every company but can't get top 3 max person_occurence

```
SELECT max(agent_occurence), company FROM table GROUP BY company;
```

Comment: which sql are you using

Comment: I'm testing on sqlite, but It can be any sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use *correlated* subquery :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1 
WHERE t1.person_occurencee = (SELECT max(t2.person_occurence) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.company = t2.company);
```

If your DBMS supports analytical function then you can also do :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by company order by person_occurrence desc) as seq 
      from t
     ) t
where seq <= 3;
```

Comment: I use sqlite and I'm not sure window functions are supported. Can you explain the first query? I dont understand where t1 and t2 are came from.

Comment: @gunes. . . `t1 & t2` are table alias & they are used as reference of `table_name` whenever same `table_name` is used more than once in single query.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by company order by person_occurrence desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Now, this assumes that you want the top 3 regardless of ties -- that is, if 4 are tied with the same highest value, this returns three of them.  Ties make things more difficult.  You may want `dense_rank()` or `rank()` instead.